# Tflearn Input shape error

Tags: neural-network, tflearn

**Error**

> "Cannot feed value of shape (128, 1) for Tensor 'TargetsData/Y:0',
>   which has shape '(?,)'".

**Code**

I have 4 classes and vocab consists of words 17355.

```
tf.reset_default_graph()
net = tflearn.input_data(shape=(None,trainX.shape[1]),name='input')
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 200, activation='ReLU')
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 25, activation='ReLU')
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 4, activation='softmax')
net = tflearn.regression(net, optimizer='sgd', 
                         learning_rate=0.1, 
                         to_one_hot = True,n_classes =4,
                         loss='categorical_crossentropy')

model = tflearn.DNN(net)
model.fit(trainX, trainY, validation_set=0.1, show_metric=True, batch_size=128, n_epoch=100)
```

trainX.shape = 12384,17355 , trainY.shape = 12384,1 , testX.shape = 1376,17355 , testY.shape = 1376,1

Answer (score 1):

**What causes this error?**

The error **”Cannot feed value of shape … for Tensor 'TargetsData/Y:0', which has shape …”** is mainly caused by that the shape of trainY is different with the placeholder shape of the estimator (regression) layer.

**Why?**

In your case, the main problem is that the shape of trainY is (?, 1) which is a 2D tensor, but the shape of the placeholder is (?,) which is an 1D tensor. So we get this error.

**How to solve it?**

Reshape the trainY to 1D tensor. For you had set the `to_one_hot = True` in the regression layer, so the placeholder shape is an 1D tensor which contains the class indices. For details you can check the [source code:tflearn/tflearn/layers/estimator.py](https://github.com/tflearn/tflearn/blob/master/tflearn/layers/estimator.py) about regression:

```
   with tf.name_scope(pscope):
        p_shape = [None] if to_one_hot else input_shape
        placeholder = tf.placeholder(shape=p_shape, dtype=dtype, name="Y")
```

So, we need to reshape the trainY from (12384,1) to (12384,) before fed to the model.